# Django: How to populate value into form template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a small form which includes something like name, mobile number, age field. All are text fields.

These values are stored in DB. 
I want my template to pre-populate the form with values from DB (if exists). How can this be done?

My template code is as below:

```
<div>
  <center><form action="/profilesettings/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form></center></div>
```

Currently, it displays form with empty field. Instead of empty fields, I would like them to show values which are fetched from DB.

Comment: This is very well covered in the documentation: [Forms for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this example on django docs

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
article.headline
'My headline'
form = ArticleForm(instance=article)

form['headline'].value()
'Initial headline'
```

Comment: Thank you. All I had to add was the instance part.